# Preventing the menu from rolling up when you have clicked on sub-menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some issues with this code.
How can i get the menu preventing from rolling up after I had chosen a category in the submenu?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.sidebar_menu ul').hide();

        $('.years').click(function(e) {
            $(this).children().slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $('.months').click(function(e) {
            $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $('.posts').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $('li[rel=<?php echo $get->menu_target ?>]').parent().slideToggle();
        $('li[rel=<?php echo $get->menu_target ?>]').parent().parent().parent().slideToggle();

    </script>
```

Comment: add **return false;** before the end of the function.

Comment: I tried to add return false;, it caused another problem, the submenu collapse function stopped working completely and now the page displays all the submenus..

Comment: Share your html, css and jQuery in a JSFiddle and I'll take a look at it when I can :)